# How to check if there is an integer in list

Tags: python, list

I am using python for a project.
I want to find if there is an Integer in my list.
I don't want to use count() or contains().
I am looking if there is an integer and not just a specific character.
Is there a way to do it.

Comment: why dont you want to use `count`   or something like `element in list` ?

Comment: i would have used count/element in but i am not looking for a specific character i what to find if there is any integer

Comment: ```if any(isinstance(j,int) for j in <list>)```?

Comment: @Sujay can you elaborate more on that

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please answer: Is this a list of strings or a list that contains several types of objects (possibly including strings)? Also, please show us a small example of your code on what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check using `.any()`, and `isinstance()`

> The `any()` function returns True if any item in an iterable are true, otherwise it returns False.

> The `isinstance()` function returns True if the specified object is of the specified type, otherwise False.

```
l1=["Hello","There",2,4,'1',"integer"]

if any(isinstance(j,int) for j in <list>):
    print("Integer found!")
else:
    print("No integer is there in the list.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the list and use `isinstance`

```
from typing import List, Any


def is_int_in_list(lst: List[Any]) -> bool:
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, int):
            return True
    return False


lst1 = ['x', 12, {}]
print(is_int_in_list(lst1))
lst2 = ['x', '12', {}]
print(is_int_in_list(lst2))
```

Comment: this can also solve my problem but it will give me negative response for every item that is not integer in list

Comment: see the latest code please

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '1.0', 's','1.2']
for i in list1:
    try:
        int(i)
        print(i , "is int")
        # return true
    except:
        print(i, "error")
```

1 is int
2 is int
1.0 error
s error
1.2 error

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, "car", "bike"]
list2 = ["yes" if type(x) == int else "no" for x in list1]
print(list2)
```